# How to understand this warning message when compiling my C files?

Tags: r, c

I am trying to write up some C script and interface it to R. Hence when it comes to compiling, I am use R CMD SHLIB in the command termina.

I have a couple of C files that I would like to compile:

file1.c

file2.c

file3.c

file4.c

file4.c depends on file1.c/file2.c/file3.c as it calls function defined in the other 3 files

file4.c also use a .h header file that I wrote up, let's call it file.h

I would like to name my compiled file be one file, let' say it is called testing.so

I put all 4 .c files and 1 .h file in the same folder, and I ran the following command in a MAC OS environment:

`R CMD SHLIB file1.c file2.c file3.c file4.c -o testing.so`

The compiling process went through without any error, and it seems to be succesful.

The message goes like this:

*using C compiler: 'Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)'
using SDK: ''

clang -arch arm64 -I"/some/path"...(omitted some info here)

clang -arch arm64 -dynamiclib -Wl, ...(omitted some info here)

und.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.frmaework/.. -framework R - Wl, -framework -W1, CoreFoundation

ld: warning: -single_module is obsolete

ld: warning: -multiply_defined is obsolete*

It appears to me the compiling is succesful, but I am a little confused by the warning message above in the last two rwos.

I have not tested the code yet, because there are more files to compile and currently it still miss pieces to actually become runnable.

Just need some illumination on whether this warning message shoudld be of concern, and what does it mean actually?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just ignore those. They are set by R itself when compiling your C code, and macOS >=11 ends up warning about these obsolete flags. They were removed roughly 7 months ago, which means that I think if you download R >=4.3.2 then you won't see them anymore. https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/a8a27343e873dd1bcf11a4cb870b08ee6c3eba43